# Java.exe error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have my Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio 2015 i'm getting this error (java.exe" exited with code 2) when i add parameters in any XML (color,layout etc). I have found some solution increase heap size changing Heap Size 1G to 2G found no difference.
Anyone please help me . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you install the google play service in your project?

Comment: yes i install google play service in my project.